# Does Twilio Whatsapp solution support messaging to a whatsapp group

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to use the Twilio API to send WhatsApp messages to a group but I could not find any support. WhatsApp Business API supports this use case, so I was wondering if Twilio has support for messaging to WhatsApp groups instead of individuals.

Looked at Twilio documentation but there wasn't any API for it.

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Under [these FAQs on the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#frequently-asked-questions-on-whatsapp-integrations), it mentions that this is not supported yet but is expected to be so in the future.

> "**Can I send messages to WhatsApp groups or manage groups?**
>
> Currently, our API does not support messaging with or managing
>   WhatsApp groups. We expect to add support for groups in the future."

Hope this helps!